# What is influenced by textColorPrimary and how to control it's side effects?

Tags: android, material-design

I have an app where i set the `colorPrimary` to a dark blue. With this the Toolbar i use as AppBar has a dark blue color and since my theme is based on `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` the text of the AppBar is (nearly) black by default. So i set `textColorPrimary` to white like this in my style:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary_default</item>
```

But as a result, now also the text in my navigation drawer is white, as well as TextViews with `textAppearanceLarge`, on a (nearly) white background.

How do i solve this issue properly? I can't believe the right way is to set a different style (one with a dark `textPrimaryColor`) to the navigation view, all text views and whatever else is influenced by `textPrimaryColor`.

Answer (score 0):

to change color of textview in navigationView only use
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

and tinting as well as stateColorList to customize it future

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- Other layout views -->

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="#009688"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

document reference[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#attr_android.support.design:itemTextColor)

Comment: This has 2 issues: 1) It only changes the color in the navigation view, but not the color in the text views and wherever else the textPrimaryColor is used. I want to avoid setting the color (either directly or through a different style) for every control. 2) Simply setting itemTextColor on the navigation view causes the text to always have this color. Usually the text color and color of the icon of checked items changes to the primaryColor, this behaviour is disabled for the if itemTextColor is set directly, while the icon still changes color.